# What is that ceiling compartment of a Boeing 737?

Tags: boeing-737, feature-identification, cabin

Does somebody know what that big box in the roof of the 737 cabin is?

[image]

Comment: That should have been explained during the safety brief, I think...

Answer (score 23):

It holds a life raft. In case of ditching in the ocean, the raft would be removed from that compartment and tossed into the water, where it would inflate.

Comment: Has that actually ever been performed, or is it more of an theoretical option?

Comment: @vidarlo  Off the top of my head, I can't think of any time it's been used, but that doesn't mean that it never has. Might actually be a worthwhile question in its own right.

Comment: @vidarlo: AFAIK, there haven't been many ditchings of an airliner, and even less successful ones. It shouldn't be hard to go through all of them and check whether at least one raft was deployed.

Comment: I believe that this compartment is meant to hold a life raft, but I have seen it many times being used just for storing items like pillows and covers or even hand luggage if they run out of other space.

Comment: Followup: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/65614/1360